# How limit access to a paragraph type by role, like it is for content types?

Tags: 8, users, paragraphs

The permissions page at `/admin/people/permissions` provides very fine grain control over which actions people can do with specific content types. How can I  add all **paragraph types** under this permission system? We have a paragraph type that is reserved only for special cases, and we don't want anyone but a certain custom editor role creating/editing them.

I've searched for a few contrib modules, but many are not updated (or just plain abandoned) with little documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply enable the *Paragraphs sub-module* **Paragraphs Type Permissions**. It provides CRUD permissions per Paragraphs Type.

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/paragraphs/tree/modules/paragraphs_type_permissions/paragraphs_type_permissions.info.yml?h=8.x-1.x

> Allows users to configure permissions for individual Paragraphs
>   types.

Comment: So it seems like this is what I'm looking for but this plugin is a little buggy. I'll check off permissions for a paragraph type under a given role and it will sometimes save them and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it personally, but there is a module that I believe should solve your problem:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_access

> Manage access and restriction to edit and view paragraphs.
>
> This module provides a node access type api to allow restriction of access to
>   paragraph items. Companion modules provide access rules, and grants which are
>   verified when rendering the entities.